# Construct ST_GEOMETRY rectangle from two vertices: lower-left and upper-right

Tags: geometry, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, rectangle

*Oracle 18c SDE.ST_GEOMETRY 10.7.1 EGDB:*

---

I have two vertices of a rectangle:

- Lower-left: 10,10
- Upper-right: 100,100

I want to construct a rectangle polygon from those two vertices using ST_GEOMETRY functions.

Is there a way to construct that rectangle using just the two vertices? Or is it only possible to construct a rectangle using all four vertices?

Comment: *Five* vertices define a rectangle (last=first)

Comment: I suppose that you are using the ESRI geometries (sde), not the native Oracle geometries (SDO). Is that right?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, that’s right. I’m using ESRI’s implementation of ST_GEOMETRY.

Comment: Ok. There seems to be a native box geometry in SDO that can be constructed with two coordinate pairs https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/wiki/index.php/Sample_Oracle_Spatial_Queries `mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(-180.0,-90.0, 180.0,90.0)`. With SDE I think you must work with min/max x/y values and construct the points for a polygon from those.